# Bound on the $L^2$-norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f, g$ are two functions on a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$, is there a bound on $\|f-g\|_2$, involving only $\|f-g\|_1$, $\|g\|_2$, and some other finite quantities? Here, $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the $L^p$-norm.

Thanks!

Comment: A bound that depends on what?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Basically, I want to show that if $\|f-g\|_1$ is finite and $\|g\|_2$ is finite, then $\|f-g\|_2$ is finite.

Comment: That is not true in general: $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $g=0$.

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be. Consider the following functions defined on $[0,1]$.

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
n&0\leq x\leq 1/n\\
0& 1/n<x\leq 1
\end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=0$$

Then $\|f_n-g\|_1=1$ for all $n$ but $\|f_n-g\|_2$ explodes.